# Easy way to blur label

Tags: iphone

Need to create blurred shadow under UILabel. Same text but with blur and offset. Since NSShadow not supported in the iPhone SDK only way I see is Quartz render. Is there simpliest solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I provide code to draw a shadow around a UILabel in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697440/how-to-draw-an-uilabel-in-drawrect/2698671#2698671) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697440/how-to-draw-an-uilabel-in-drawrect).  For an example of this in action, see the [sample project](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/QuartzExamples.zip) I've created.  A shadow of the same color as the text provides a nice blurring effect to the text in a label.

Answer (score 0):

For 3.1 and below, no. You must use CoreGraphics.

For 3.2 and above, you can get the `layer`, and set the [`shadowRadius` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW85).