# Handle 8 labels on single cell in UITABLEVIEW

Tags: iphone

I want to use different information and use different format,lines for information,when i drag down then the UITable view is not run smooth...What will i do?

Answer (score 0):

As a direct quote from WWDC 2010

Use drawRect: to create the contents of the UITableViewCell.
It is more efficient way in your case. And you can add images and other objects too.

Comment: In drawRect, i am using labels...but its not a good technique...give another alternative

Comment: you can follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697440/how-to-draw-an-uilabel-in-drawrect